# How to specify font sizes in plots with multiple plots per page?

Tags: r, knitr

When I generate a .pdf file using knitr from within RStudio, single plots exhibit the desired font sizes of axis labels, legend, etc. However, when I use the layout() function to generate multiple sub-plots, these font sizes are reduced. Please see the example code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
<<settings, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
# set tikz default options
opts_chunk$set(
  out.width='15cm',
  fig.width=5.906, # inch
  fig.height=5.906, # inch
  dev='tikz',
  fig.align='center',
  fig.lp='fig:',
  fig.env='figure*',
  dev.args=list(pointsize=10),
  message=FALSE, 
  echo=FALSE
)
options(tikzDefaultEngine = "pdftex")
@
<<singlePlot, fig.cap="single plot with good font size">>=
par(cex=1)
plot(rnorm(100))
@
<<multiplePlots, fig.cap="multiple plots with fonts being too small">>=
par(cex=1)
layout(matrix(1:9, 3))
for(i in 1:9) plot(rnorm(100))
@
\end{document}
```

How do I get fonts in the second plot to be of the same size as the ones in the first plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my, I figured it out by myself just 30 seconds after posting the question...

The trick is to reverse the order of layout() and par() in the second plot, like so:

```
<<multiplePlots, fig.cap="multiple plots with fonts being just right">>=
layout(matrix(1:9, 3))
par(cex=1)
for(i in 1:9) plot(rnorm(100))
@
```

This works as expected.

So it seems that layout() calls par() internally to set a new (smaller) character expansion value when setting up multiple plots. Thus setting par(cex=1) before layout had no effect. I had not known this, but it makes sense. Sorry for the unneccessary disturbance.

Comment: Hi @UncertainVagery, if you realised your mistake, you could either delete your question or, when the time restriction on accepting your own answers passes (I think it's four hours maybe?), accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I shall accept it as an answer once the time passes (system says "wait 2 days"). Maybe I will run into the same problem again at some point in the future and then find my own answer to it ;)